# Cast parameters during mocking of class Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, casting, mockito

When I mock the class in the following way(in Kotlin) 
`val card: Card = mock<Card>()` it automatically initializes all its parameters(cardNumber,expMonth,expYear,CVC) as String, since they are saved as String. However in the code(Java) which I am about to test I initialize class card in the following way

```
Card card = new Card(mView.getCreditCardNumber(),
                     Integer.valueOf(mView.getMonth()),
                     Integer.valueOf(mView.getYear()),
                     mView.getCVV());
```

I already mocked those values in the following way

```
whenever(mView.creditCardNumber).then { "1234567890123456" }
whenever(mView.month).then { "12" }
whenever(mView.year).then { "2022" }
whenever(mView.cvv).then { "123" }
```

So the difference is that middle 2 parameters should be Integers, while I can not do that. I tried the following solution

```
whenever(mView.month).then { 12 }
whenever(mView.year).then { 2022 }
```

But I got CastException from Int to String. Since mView.month/year are supposed to be Strings.

So, is there a way to make this cast, otherwise I am not able to correctly test the rest of a code. Please help, or I am going crazy. Thanks :) !

Comment: Could you please rephrase the problem? Why can't you just `assertEquals("12", card.month)`?

Comment: What is the `mView.getMonth()` method's return type?

Comment: I don't need to test that. I need to stub card.validateCard by setting it to true in order to continue testing. But for this, I need card to be initialized correctly, otherwise it does not let me do it.

Comment: The return type is String

Comment: And why do you want it to return integer? I believe your Card constructor should work if you return string from `mView.getMonth()`

Comment: Please don't put up **pseudo code**. But up a **real** [mcve]. Alone the fact that you just put up something and explain what it is supposed to do ... makes it close to impossible to answer your question. Simple give us the kotlin code that you use to initialize your card object. Again [mcve]